# XmlSerializer with multiple classes

Tags: xmlserializer

What's the best way to serialize multiple classes with XmlSerializer in one file? Ideally, what I want is to have one root node and the XmlSerializer serializes one child node to this root node, one per class.

Otherwise, my other idea is to just make a wrapper that contains these classes and serialize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the objects you want to serialize into a collection and then serialize the collection using the XmlSerializer.